# lxc containers on another partition

Tags: mount, ubuntu-server, lxc

I have created two containers(say TestOneContainer and TestTwoContainer) in ubuntu server using LXC. Now the lxc filesystem is in /home folder and two containers also use /home folder. I have created two partition(100 GB for TestOneContainer and 200 GB for TestTwoContainer) for those two containers while Ubuntu server OS installation. I want to mount TestOneContainer in 100 GB space and TestTwoContainer in 200 GB space. How can I do this?

I have tried these commands from this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html)

create and symlink two directories:

```
sudo mkdir /srv/lxclib /srv/lxccache
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/lxc /var/cache/lxc
sudo ln -s /srv/lxclib /var/lib/lxc
sudo ln -s /srv/lxccache /var/cache/lxc
```

or, using bind mounts:

```
sudo mkdir /srv/lxclib /srv/lxccache
sudo sed -i '$a \
/srv/lxclib /var/lib/lxc    none defaults,bind 0 0 \
/srv/lxccache /var/cache/lxc none defaults,bind 0 0' /etc/fstab
sudo mount -a
```

But these commands are to mount lxc in different filesystem not TestOneContainer or TestTwoContainer.

Answer (score 1):

suppose 100GB free space is under /mnt/sd1 and 200GB is under /mnt/sd2, and you want to mount them under /work in containers, use following commands to mount it to the containers:

```
#create mount point from host
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lxc/TestOneContainer/rootfs/work
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lxc/TestTwoContainer/rootfs/work

#mount them from host
sudo mount --bind /mnt/sd1/ /var/lib/lxc/TestOneContainer/rootfs/work
sudo mount --bind /mnt/sd2/ /var/lib/lxc/TestTwoContainer/rootfs/work
```

Then start the containers, and you will see /work with that big space with

```
df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [LXC source](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-conf), specifically to the section

[**Host Setup**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-hostsetup) -->
    **Using a separate filesystem for the container store**.

There is a very clear explanation.